# What were the requirements in order for a man to become a burgher (or citizen) in German cities in the middle ages?

Tags: middle-ages, germany, guilds

I really need some help answering this question. Could a man who lived in another town or part of Germany, for example East Frisia, about 1500 AD, go to Bremen for example and become a burgher there? What were the requirements he had to meet in order to become a citizen? Would joining a guild automatically give him citizenship status? What requirements did guilds have for those coming into cities from elsewhere?

Comment: Would that not be a berger rather than a burger?

Comment: They will vary by city and by guild; there was no coherent governance across German cities (because there was no Germany).  Guilds could not confer citizenship - citizenship is a concept that arises from government; guilds are extra-governmental.   Bremen in 1500 appears to have been an ecclesiastical state, so governance was exercised by an Archbishop.  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizenship#Middle_Ages ) implies that citizenship may have been a legitimate status, but I'm not convinced.

Comment: If you're interested in Bremen, I'd begin by studying [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archbishopric_of_Bremen#Constitution_and_Politics_within_the_Prince-Archbishopric) and expand my research from there.  If there was a constitution, you should be able to get a copy and study how citizenship was determined.

Comment: And the spelling of Burgher is correct; see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizenship#Middle_Ages)

Comment: @Anixx - I don't think that comment generates the welcoming tone that I hope to see in H:SE.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I'm going to see if I can find a copy of the Constitution of Bremen circa 1500. As I understand it, you could not belong to a guild without first being a Burgher. This was a way of protecting against guild members from other cities from coming in. So guild membership implied that you were a already a Burgher. The process of gaining citizenship involved having someone who was already a citizen "zu bürgen" for you. Thank you again for your advice.

Comment: Those details (appropriately sourced) would have made this a fantastic question.

Answer (score 3):

As Bremen is only an example (random, as far as I know) given above, I will answer based on Reval, which was given city rights based on those valid in Lübeck (therefore Lübeck had its place as a court of appeals for any claims against Reval).

The situation that applied was that any serf who escaped and lived in the town for **a year and one day** would be free from any reprisal by the landlord -- which presumably answers the question as after this point these people would have been primarily responsible to city law and not a specific landlord. This was beneficial to the cities as they'd gain cheap labour.

The (German) saying ['Stadtluft macht frei'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadtluft_macht_frei) is used to symbolise this principle. The Wikipedia article, however, suggests that HRE law superseded that whilst I know of instances in 16th century Reval where the principle was still used to avoid serfdom. Therefore, I would think that either Lübeck's status as a Hanseatic city or the Freie Städte concept within the HRE allowed it and cities which derived law from it to maintain this concept.